# Make Flash Movies not downloadable

Tags: flash, code-access-security

is there any way, to hide the source of a flash in the sourcecode, so that the movie itsself is not downloadable, or better not to copy?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. If it's viewable, it's downloadable. You could make it hard to obtain, like forcing an AJAX call to create the content of the `<object>` dynamically, using a POST request to a PHP page which doesn't allow viewing of the file without that POST.

Basically, if you are giving the file to the user, it's theirs and you can't stop them from doing things with it.